# setOnClickListener doesn't work (as I want)

Tags: java, android

I have code like this below. It works (run without any error), however it seems button doesn't call method `boardMaker()` properly. Furthermore two previous lines doesn't work either. When I comment line with `boardMaker` call. It works. Any suggestions why this call paralyze my button?

(refresh is RelativeLayout)

```
refresh.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        refresh.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        resultDisplay.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        boardMaker(1);
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the code inside `boardMaker()`?

Comment: It's a bit complicated>> https://codeshare.io/DtDHR
I call it also at onCreate method and it works fine.

Comment: add a try and catch block inside the onClick function and see what error is being caught.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason why the lines of code inside the onClickListener block would not work you're syntax is perfect.

Please show us boardMaker() method.

Your button getting paralyzed could be a sign of a blocking call made in boardMaker().

Comment: Seems pretty clear to me that your code is in an infinite loop inside boardMaker().
This is the reason why your button seems paralyzed upon click but works with boardMaker() commented out.

I would suggest you add debug points and step inside the boardMaker() and investigate this infinite loop, and also add more logs within the method which will help you understand whats going on.

Comment: yeah that was it. There was infinite loop caused by my wrong thinking. Thank you very much for help.